# Lint give different result when run in eclipse and command prompt

Tags: eclipse, random

I am trying to find all unused resources in my android project. But when i am running Lint via Eclipse and when i run it from command line the results are different. The number of unused resources shown by Lint in eclipse is much more than when its run from command line. can anyone tell me the reason?

Comment: Note: I am considering only unused resources in both the cases.

Comment: Even this will help me. Can i save the result shown by Lint when used in Eclipse in some file like xml. For now i am doing it via command line and by command line i am not getting correct result.